# Getting the EXACT coords of Mouse in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Alright, I know HOW to do but It's doing something weird.

I am trying to get the correct X Y coords for a `JMenu` to appear. I've found a way but it's only a hack. All the right-clicking takes place on the `JList`, for now until I add character panel, so let's say you right-click near the top-left. You expect the Y coord to be around 40~ pixels and the Y coord to be around 100~ pixels right? Because you're clicking on the near left where the `JList` is. Wrong. The x y coords count from the top left of the `JList` when I want it to count from the top left of the WHOLE application. :S

So, what did I do? Since the Y coord is correct, I added 512 pixels to the X coord so it's always in the JList. Like so:

```
                int newMouseX = 512+e.getX();
                popup.show(tileOffline.this, newMouseX, e.getY()); // show item at mouse
```

However, as you can tell I will not be right-clicking in the `JList` forever.

How can I make it so I get the exact X Y coords of the mouse from the WHOLE applet?

Here's a pic to describe the situation WITHOUT the 512 hack:
[image]

Comment: You've bee given the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Bring up a Popup Menu" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854185/jlist-right-click-shows-menu-use-drop-cancel). The code you need is in the tutorial. Read the tutorial. Run the code example. Understand the code examples. Post your SSCCE (not a picture) when you have problems. It gets frustrating when we take the time to answer your questions and you can't even read the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you're making this harder than it needs to be.  The popup menu will position itself relative to the component you pass into the show method ([JPopupMenu API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29)).  You should just be able to show the popupmenu doing something like this in order to get it to show at the correct location:

```
popup.show(myJList, e.getX(), e.getY());
```

Comment: Good point; see also http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup

Comment: @Jahkr, you where given this answer 2 days ago!!

Comment: Yes.. I know that. That's why I said thanks. Now please get off my question -- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) has methods suitable for converting to and from screen coordinates, as well as among `Components`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use convertPointToScreen in `javax.swing.SwingUtilities` to convert to screen coordinates - just pass in the component that you're clicking!

```
convertPointToScreen(Point p, Component c)
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html

Answer (score 0):

**Use the `MouseEvent.getXOnScreen()` and `MouseEvent.getYOnScreen()` methods.**

The `MouseEvent` that gets generated when you move or click a mouse contains the absolute coordinates on the screen.  Use these two methods to get them.