# Get jTable row number from popup item

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

I have a jTable as from the attached picture [image]

Right click on a row starts a jPopup, with a single item "Thread Stop".

I would like to return the row number by clicking on this menu item

How to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the row number?

Comment: Can you add some code where you associate jPopup content "Thread Stop" with a specific row number? It seems you are able to associate them right so you should be able to access row number easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your MouseListener where you show your popup, simply get the row and column numbers via the JTable methods:

```
  table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
        int col = table.columnAtPoint(p);

        System.out.printf("row, col: [%d, %d]%n", row, col);

        // show pop-up menu here

     }
  });
```

Comment: +1 for faster @Alberto acepsut look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423533/jtable-with-jpopupmenu

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) includes the row as a parameter, but you should act only when the `TableModel` is updated, as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) here. [`TablePopupEditor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) is a related example.