# How to adapt left-click action on JTable to the right-click in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseleftbuttondown, jpopup

I have a `JTable` which I want to have left-click and right-click `JPopupMenu` on it.
Normaly by left-click on the JTable you can  select a row. I would like to do the same with right-click plus show up a popup menu.
**Does anybody know how to do this?**

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
               //this line gives wrong result because table.getSelectedRow() stay alwase on the same value
               codeModel.setSelectedFileName(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
               JPopupMenu popup = createRightClickPopUp();
               popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
           }else{
               codeModel.setSelectedFileName(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
               codeTextArea.setText(codeModel.getCodeContents());
           }
       }
   });
```

Comment: Why not add a popupmenu to the mouse wheel too? would be fun I guess. Anyway, back to seriousness, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { //or mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
       if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
           //-- select a row
           int idx = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
           table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(idx, idx);
           //---
           codeModel.setSelectedFileName(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
           JPopupMenu popup = createRightClickPopUp();
           popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
       }else{
           codeModel.setSelectedFileName(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
           codeTextArea.setText(codeModel.getCodeContents());
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- please read my question [JTable with JPopupMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423533/jtable-with-jpopupmenu)
- most important is [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)'s type
- minor for your question, but both answers there are correct and great

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the clicked row easily enough using JTable.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint()) in your mouse listener.