# Target specific JXTable column values to open in a new frame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, swingx

How can I target (in JXTable) a specific column values from different rows to open a new frame when I double click?

[image]

I have this code for now:

```
myTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    JXTable target = (JXTable)e.getSource();
                    int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                    int column = target.getTableColumn(3);  //for example the third column
                    new Detail().setVisible(true);

                }
            }
        });
```

Solved with this code:

```
     final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane((Frame) null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

     final JDialog d = pane.createDialog((Frame) null, "Comments");
                   d.setModal(false);
                   d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                   d.pack();
     myTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                   if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                          int row = myTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                          Object value1 = myTable.getValueAt(row, 4);
                          pane.setMessage(value1);
                   if (!d.isVisible())
                   d.setLocationRelativeTo(myTable);
                   d.setVisible(true);
                   }
          }
      });
```

UPDATE 1:

As @mKorbel said, I want to use a JPopupMenu like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423533/jtable-with-jpopupmenu) (provided by @mKorbel). But how can I implement a JDialog which opens when the JMenuItem is clicked.

```
private void createPopupMenu() {
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem MenuItemComments = new JMenuItem("Show Comments");
        JMenuItem MenuItemReference = new JMenuItem("Show Reference");
        popup.add(MenuItemComments);
        popup.add(MenuItemReference);

        MouseListener popupListener = new PopupListener(popup);
        Table_Employee.addMouseListener(popupListener);
    }

private class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private JPopupMenu popup;
        PopupListener(JPopupMenu popupMenu) {
            popup = popupMenu;
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            maybeShowPopup(e);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (Table_Employee.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }
        }
        private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {

        // get row that pointer is over
        int row = Table_Employee.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());

        // if pointer is over a selected row, show popup
        if (Table_Employee.isRowSelected(row)) {
           popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());

        }
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't create a new `J(X)Frame` on runtime, contents of this container will be the same, no reason for that, create that once time, reuse this container, and for visibility on the screen (to `hide / show)` use `setVisible(false / true)`
2. don't create a `J(X)Frame`, create a `J(X)Dialog` with parent to the `JXTable`, then dialog will be centered to the `JXTables`
3. you can to use `ListSelectionListener` too, but with single selection model
4. read Oracle tutorial about `JList`, `JTable` and `ListSelectionListener`, logics will be the same and for `SwingX components` too,
5. I'd be use [JPopup as control for displaying the JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423533/jtable-with-jpopupmenu), just to avoids annoying events came from mouse or keyboard

EDIT

have to add

- `d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`, then `JDialog` never will be closed only changed to the `setVisible(false);`
- have to code value from selected `JTable`s row,
- create a new, separate void that fills value from `JTable`s row to the `JComponent`s placed into `JDialog`
- be ensure that `J(X)Table` has changed `selectionMode` to the `single selection`
- (not required) now you can possitioning `JDialog` on the screen, `JDialog` still is not visible on the screen
- thenafter to call `d.setVisble(true)`, I'd suggest wrap this code line to the `invokeLater()`, then `JDialog` will be visible after all changes are done, move this event to the end of the `Event Dispatch Thread`

Comment: I have a popup menu called from specific cell from a JXTable. But the problem now is how can I implement inside popup a JDialog to come up. See the UPDATE 1 please.