# MouseListener is giving problems with show() method

Tags: java, swing, jtable, illegalstateexception, jpopupmenu

I want to display a small context menu when a user right clicks a table row in my application. My plan was to use a custom made `MouseListener` for this that calls the `show()` method. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class TableMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    JTable table = (JTable)(e.getSource());
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
    int col = table.columnAtPoint(p);

// The autoscroller can generate drag events outside the Tables range.
if ((col == -1) || (row == -1)) {
        return;
}

    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu("Row "+row);
        JMenuItem menu1 = new JMenuItem("Wijzigen");
        menu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //do things, still have to make that
            }
        });
        pop.show(menu1, p.x, p.y);

    }
}
}
```

Now my problem is: when i run my application, and I right click a table row, it pops out this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(Unknown Source)
at TableMouseListener.mousePressed(TableMouseListener.java:34)
```

What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `JMenuItem` isn't added to the `JPopup`, then `JMenuItem` shoudn't be `isDisplayable`
- prepare this container, dont't to create on fly ,
- create whole popup container as local variable or as returns from class, void, whatever

  a) prepare with `JMenuItems` too

  b) override `maybeShowPopup`, then there you can manage whatever (must be done on EDT)
- [rest of importantn methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423533/jtable-with-jpopupmenu)

Comment: With the rest of important methods you mean the `maybeShowPopup` methods?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to display JPopupMenu (pop) relatively to the JMenuItem (menu1) component. But JMenuItem is not visible in the moment when you call popupmenu `show` method and it fails to determine JMenuItem location on screen (ofcourse, it is not shown on the screen yet).

You have to use some visible component in the popupmenu `show` method as the first argument (for example some button that is added to displayed frame or any other **actually visible** component). You can also pass null to place the popup menu relatively to the (0;0) coordinate (upper-left screen corner).

Comment: Hmmm i must be messing up bigtime then. What i actually want to do is show the JPopupMenu with the JMenuItem in it, at the location of my mousepointer... :|

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel so basically you want to overwrite default sub-menu location and use the mouse location instead of the default right-sided positioning? And yes, your code indeed does something really messy :)

Comment: Yes, because by default, the submenu pops up in the upper left corner of the screen. My general idea was to just have a context menu pop up when a user right-clicks a table row. I want the menu to show the option to edit the table row data. This opens another small frame with one textfield and a button that says 'send'. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel in that case you should have opened the JPopupMenu relative to your table and just pass the table cell coordinates. Just that simple :)

Comment: Yes i got it all working by following mKorbels link he mentioned above. But thanks for your help as well :)