# Trying to Get value from "JTable" and and set it to "Jtextfield"

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I saw some same questions like mine on here but not all of them including my question.. I want to Get value from "JTable" and and set it to "Jtextfield". I wrote the code, but it doesnt work. Here is my code:

```
private void Table_EmployeeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{                                            
        int row =Table_Employee.getSelectedRow();
        String Table_click=(Table_Employee.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        try{
        String sql ="select * from KYaziciProg where \"Müşteri Adı\"='"+Table_click+"' ";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){

        String add1 =rs.getString("Yapılan İşlem");
        jTextField2.setText(add1);

        String add2 =rs.getString("Müşteri Adı");
        jTextField1.setText(add2);

        String add3 =rs.getString("Ürünün Cinsi");
        jTextField3.setText(add3);

        String add4 =rs.getString("Ürünün Miktarı");
        jTextField4.setText(add4);

        String add5 =rs.getString("Ürünün Fiyatı");
        jTextField5.setText(add5);

        String add6 =rs.getString("Ürünün Tutarı");
        jTextField6.setText(add6);

        String add7 =rs.getString("İşlem Tarihi");
        jTextField7.setText(add7);

        String add8 =rs.getString("Ödeme Vadesi");
        jTextField8.setText(add8);

        String add9 =rs.getString("Yapılan Ödeme");
        jTextField9.setText(add9);

        String add10 =rs.getString("Kalan Bakiye");
        jTextField10.setText(add10);
        }
       }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       } 
    }
```

Comment: From code i would say that you want get value from JTable and use it in sql (and JTextField has nothing to do with this). Please specify what exactly doesn't work - what is wrong?

Comment: Yeah you understood it true. Exactly the problem is, When i run the program, i clicked to table's a random row;it didnt show me on JTextFields which is next to the table. Here, i can give you a screenshot about that. http://i.imgur.com/BqMJCD6.png

Comment: So there are blank values in all columns in table, or nothing has been selected from database. Did you print real value of Table_click and did you test that something is selected from database?

Comment: Meh maybe :) And thanks anyway, mKorbel's answer is true :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. add `pst.close();` and `rs.close();` to finally block (`try - catch - finally`), otherwise these Objects increasing JVM memory
2. to try to avoid to use `MouseListener` for this job meaning `private void Table_EmployeeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)`,
3. each of mouse click to invoke JDBC, but there isn't some guarantee

   - any of row is selected, because MouseEvents by default not only to select cell, row or column in JTable
   - only one cell, row or column is selected, otherwise you would need to solve arrays of selected cell, rows, columns
   - added ListSelectionListener
   - changed ListSelectionMode to SINGLE

EDIT

- [use action from JPopup for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423533/jtable-with-jpopupmenu), invoke JDBC from JPopup rather than from Mouse or ListSelectionListerner, then you can use all mouse a key events inside JTable without care of if is JDBC invoked
- then I miss there testing (otherwise ArraysOf or NPE exception) pseudocode

.

```
   int row =Table_Employee.getSelectedRow();
   if (row > -1) {  // no selection
     // now is possible to determine value
     // note see my next point about following code line
     // Table_Employee.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString() 
   }
```

.

- JTables view can be sorted or filtered, column reordered, removed from view, then indexing from selected cell, row, column doesn't equals to indexing in underlaying XxxTableModel, is required to convert views index to models index more [see Oracle tutorial description about convertXxxToXxx with note NOTE: When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)
- maybe, by default isn't required that, JTables view can returns the same value untill this value isn't modified somehow in TableCellRenderer
- remove redutant code line (in the case that in Database isn't allowed null, otherwise you have to test `if(rs.getString("Yapılan İşlem"))!= null)`)

.

```
String add1 = rs.getString("Yapılan İşlem");
jTextField2.setText(add1);

could be with success

jTextField2.setText((rs.getString("Yapılan İşlem")).trim());
```

Comment: Thanks man, i conver t them to "jTextField2.setText((rs.getString("Yapılan İşlem")).trim());" and changed JTextField's names as mines , and it WORKS ! ^^